# Access VBA - build a query that joins all tables in the database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got database linked to the Sharepoint and each day I make cut-offs - I've got for it a simple macro. As a result I have number of tables called "Progress tracking " & appropriate date.

What is needed for me this is a query which compares one column from all tables.

It should looks like:

```
Select 
    a.[Unique identifier], a.[Escalation reason], 
    b.[escalation reason], ..., 
    z.[escalation reason]
from 
    ([Progress tracking & date a 
left join 
    [Progress tracking * b on a.[unique identifier] = b.[unique identifier]) 
left join 
    [Progress tracking * c on a.[unique identifier] = c.[unique identifier])
... 
left join 
    [Progress tracking * z on a.[unique identifier] = z.[unique identifier]
```

I wonder if this is possible using VBA code. I started using for each table in `db.tabledefs`, however I do not know how to go further.

I would appreciate any suggestion

Regards

Comment: Have you considered a single table with a [tracking date] field set to "=Date()"? This way, when you import to the table the field defaults to the current day and then you only have to run queries against the date range you need.

Answer (score 0):

Join all the linked tables from Sharepoint may not be the best idea.
Sharepoint data are stored in SQL db, so when you query data from Sharepoint, it goes through web services, then to multiple tables/views in the sql db, the performance won't be satisfying compares to querying over SQL DB directly, (but Sharepoint won't allow you to query SQL DB in general).

I'd suggest if you really want to join tables linked from Sharepoint lists in MS Access, you can consider create multiple queries, each query only join a few tables, and you can then generate a temp table from each query, and then use those temp table as aggregated data for next level query.

hope that helps.